# Can I use javascript libraries/plugins to create heatmap without a "map" in the background?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, data-visualization, heatmap, d3heatmap

I am currently working on a web-based project that aims to visualize eye-tracking data. I want to create a heatmap (like in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wflgz.jpg)) using javascript but I want to put my heatmap as a layer on an another image instead of an actual map. I have been searching some of the libraries/plugins on the internet and found some stuff like Leaflet, heatmap.js, D3.js, etc... However, I have noticed that they generally use an actual map for the background and longitude/latitude variables for the coordinates. I would be glad if you could show me if there is a way to do it without an actual map. The data will be provided before the visualization (x-y coordinates, durations of fixations)

[Heatmap for eye-tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wflgz.jpg)

Comment: did you read about heatmaps in wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map#Types

Comment: @aksappy yes I did, honestly, I can't say that it was useful in my case

Comment: Okay, d3 can do this, actually you can build your own library.. but hassle might not be worth it. Have a look at this. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3074470